# Set a constant object variable's fields

Tags: c#

I am creating a class to group all constant variables used throughout my application, and have two Object variables of type PictureBox.

For example:

```
public const PictureBox availablePic = new PictureBox();
public const PictureBox unavailablePic = new PictureBox();
```

But if I declare them as constant, then I have to set them to what they will be throughout the application, which is what I would like to do for the Image property.

So my question is, how would I declare the properties of my Object type constants at their declaration?

I'm mainly a Java programmer, so I'm looking for how to do this the right way in C#.

Comment: This won't compile, even *without* setting any fields.

Comment: I think you're confusing `static` with `const`.

Comment: @Servy Can you elaborate on why it wouldn't? I have that exact line in my code atm, and I'm not getting any errors or warnings.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange But if I don't want the values for them to change, they should be const no? Wouldn't static allow this?

Comment: @JWiley you should be getting a compile error:  `A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null.`

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the comments, for any variable that is not a primitive, the `const` keyword will not work. Instead you can use a combination of the `static` and `readonly` keywords.

To initialize them, use a their constructor, an object initializer or add a static constructor to your class. Considering your choice of object, a static constructor may be best. Static constructors work like object constructors, but are run only once, the first time a class is used. They are specifically for initializing static components.

To declare one, use the `static` keyword (again) in front of what will look like a parameterless constructor. For example: `static MyClass()`

So, your code may look something like:

```
class MyClass
{
   public static readonly PictureBox availablePic = new PictureBox();
   public static readonly PictureBox unavailablePic = new PictureBox();

   static MyClass()
   {
      // Initialize the picture boxes here.
      availablePic.Image = Image.FromFile("available.png");
   }

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks- I'll probably end up doing something like this, but with Image instead of `PictureBox` for the declaration. Also, I edited your answer as the function is Image.FromFile().

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with a mutable reference type (which `PictureBox` is). You can use `readonly`, but in that case the *reference* will be read-only.  There's nothing stopping a client from changing the *properties* of the referenced object (which would affect all other clients that have the same reference).

There's no way to create a PictureBox that cannot be changed.  If you want to return a "constant" *image* than make *that* readonly.  You could also provide read-only *properties* that return a new `PictureBox` reference set to the "constant" image.  That way if a client changes one `PictureBox` the others are unaffected.

```
private readonly Image availablePic ;
private readonly Image unavailablePic ;

// initialize images in static constructor

public static PictureBox UnavailablePic
{
   get{
       return new PictureBox {Image = unavailablePic};
   }
}

public static PictureBox AvailablePic
{
   get{
       return new PictureBox {Image = availablePic};
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `readonly`, not `const`, as you want to assign something that is not a compile time literal.  To initialize the data you have several options:

1. Use an object initializer:

   ```
   public static readonly PictureBox box = new PictureBox() { Value = "sample" };
   ```
2. Use a static method to initialize the object:

   ```
   public static readonly PictureBox box = CreatePicturebox();

   public static PictureBox CreatePicturebox()
   {
       PictureBox box = new PictureBox();
       box.Value = "sample";
       return box;
   }
   ```
3. Use a static constructor

   ```
   public class Foo
   {
       public static readonly PictureBox box;

       static Foo()
       {
           box = new PictureBox();
           box.Value = "sample";
       }
   }
   ```

Also keep in mind that if `PictureBox` is a mutable type, that making this field `readonly` only means that the reference can never be changed to reference another object.  It does *not* meant that the object itself cannot be mutated.  You'll want to either make the object immutable, or provide an immutable wrapper that is what you expose publicly, if that is your intent.

Answer (score 1):

`const` only works with literals (e.g. `1`, `"foo"`). What you will need is `static readonly` which marks a field being accessible by the type and the reference is not modifiable. (I would use an `Image` instead of a `PictureBox` since `PictureBox` is a winforms control not data).

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static readonly Image AvailablePic =
        (Image)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("AvailablePic");
    public static readonly Image UnavailablePic =
        (Image)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("UnavailablePic");
}
```

This way you can reference the fields in your code:

```
var pic = Constants.AvailablePic;
```

However if you need to load these values before the application initializes I would avoid using `static readonly` and instead use an interface with only a getter:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    public Image AvailablePic { get; }
    public Image UnavailablePic { get; }
}

public class Configuration : IConfiguration
{
    public Configuration(Image availablePic, Image unavailablePic)
    {
        AvailablePic = availablePic;
        UnavailablePic = unavailablePic;
    }

    public Image AvailablePic { get; private set; }
    public Image UnavailablePic { get; private set; }
}
```

This way you can pass the `IConfiguration` to the objects that need this information.

e.g. In a WinForms project you could pass it to the form class constructor.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MainViewModel(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        InitializeControls();
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void MakeAvailable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox.BackgroundImage = _configuration.AvailablePic;
    }

    public void MakeUnavailable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox.BackgroundImage = _configuration.UnavailablePic;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `readonly` keyword which allows only one assignment, e.g.

```
public readonly PictureBox availablePic = new PictureBox() {
  // Put all required properties here
  BackColor = Color.AliceBlue,
  BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
  ...
};

public readonly PictureBox unavailablePic = new PictureBox();
```

Comment: I need to set the object properties as well.

Comment: @JWiley: You can put them just after constructing the instance, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

If you expose a PictureBox, the consuming code can change its Image. No way around it. Your only recourse if you want to show a PictureBox without letting the consuming code access its Image property is to encapsulate it in your own custom control.

Comment: As other answers have pointed out, readonly only applies to the reference. They wouldn't be able to replace your picturebox with another instance of the control. It doesn't prevent them from changing properties on the control. The only way to do that is to not expose the control at all.

Comment: As for writing your wrapper control, it would be a pretty simple one. Look here for info on writing composite controls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6hws6h2t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx